# WooCommerce checkout fields get mistaken for login fields by browsers ISSUE

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, checkout

On WooCommerce I have “Allow customers to create an account during checkout” enabled, which adds the `Username` and `Password` fields at checkout so the customer can create an account.

If a user that has an account on my website, but is logged out, enters the checkout page using **Chrome**, the `Email`, `Username` and `Password` fields at checkout get automatically pre-filled with the user’s existing account information. Screenshot: https://ibb.co/Db21PTp

The same issue happens on **Safari** as well. When I enter the checkout page while logged out, I immediately get directed to the `Email` field and prompted to log in with my existing account information. Screenshot: https://ibb.co/f9bvXjz

But it doesn’t make sense to use existing account information at checkout as the `Email`, `Username` and `Password` fields at checkout are for creating a new account, not logging into an existing one.

I think that it’s important to note that when I log in to my WordPress account, I always check the “Remember me” checkbox and I have saved my website login details to both of the browsers.

So most likely the `Email`, `Password` and `Username` fields in the checkout page mislead the browsers into thinking these are login fields, when they're not.

**Is there a way to “tell” the browsers that these fields at checkout are not login fields?**

Answer (score 0):

Preventing browser prompt is a bit tricky since most of the majors removed `autocomplete="false"`.

I've noticed quite a lot of different behaviour across all of them, and right now there is no real standard way to approach this issue.

All javascript approach tryin to fix that issue are causing problems on the mobile version with the numpad not showing up.

`-webkit-text-security:disc;` combine with a text `<input>` should be discouraged as [this isn't supported by IE and Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-security#browser_compatibility).

I've add some success with removing `type="password"` and switching to `type="text"` and using name attributes different than password or login or any other synonym. (eg: `pw_9394792`, `lg_9394792`). Coupled with `color:transparent;text-shadow:black 0 0 10px;` to visually hide the password.

```
<input type="text" name="lg_9394792">
<input type="text" name="pw_9394792" style="color:transparent;text-shadow:black 0 0 10px;">
```

Something else I've tried and was working not so long ago, was, setting a dummy form at the top of your page.

```
<form style="height:0;max-height:0;background:transparent;color:transparent;border:none;" data-description="dummy">
<input type="email" style="height:0;max-height:0;background:transparent;color:transparent;border:none;" data-description="email"></input>
<input type="text" style="height:0;max-height:0;background:transparent;color:transparent;border:none;" data-description="username"></input>
<input type="password" style="height:0;max-height:0;background:transparent;color:transparent;border:none;" data-description="password"></input>
<input type="submit" style="height:0;max-height:0;background:transparent;color:transparent;border:none;" data-description="submit">
</form>
```

There is a really popular thread right now about it that has been going on for nearly 3 years about it on Github, see @ https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8.